# MIPS internal logic signals for a beq instructions

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

I'd really need a hand or two with this Assembly Mips CPU Excercise.

I have to determine input and output from: ALU(s), Jump-related MUX and from the Register File.

PC is 0x01D0 and the instruction I have to simulate is: `beq $3, $7, -120`

[image]

Regarding the ALU(s) I've no problem on those, I've got issues on MUX and RG.

As you can see on the image on the second jump-related MUX I don't know what to write regarding jump address [31-0].

The other problem I've got is within the Register File, I don't know what to write as input.(Instruction should be: *0x1067FFE2*)